# why i cannot delete my node with reference

Tags: c++

```
void deleteElement(LinkedListElement<char> *&pending)
{
    if (pending->Next) {
        char value = pending->Next->Data;
        pending->Data = value;
        LinkedListElement<char> *temp = pending->Next;
        pending->Next = pending->Next->Next;
        delete temp;
    }else{
        delete pending;
        pending = NULL;
    }
}

LinkedListElement<char> *l1 = new LinkedListElement<char>('a');
LinkedListElement<char> *l2 = new LinkedListElement<char>('b');
LinkedListElement<char> *l3 = new LinkedListElement<char>('a');
LinkedListElement<char> *l4 = new LinkedListElement<char>('c');
l1->setNext(l2); l2->setNext(l3); l3->setNext(l4);

printLinkedList(l1);
deleteElement(l4);
printLinkedList(l1);
```

Simple tricky delete node in C++ what i want to ask is in the else statement, if the linked list is end , so i can just delete the end itself.

but the two print function, will always print abac, and second way abac.
because i just pass the parameter with reference, (&), i think if i want to delete l4
i do not need to change l3->Next, becasue i can change l4 to NULL, and l3->Next will be NULL.

i try to use

```
delete pending; pending=NULL;
```

why it is does not work, two print function always print abac

Comment: I really like your title.

Comment: What happens that leads you to believe you can't?

Comment: You should try to explain what your actual problem is, is it a compile issue, runtime? as Chris says - what happens

Comment: I CHANGE IT, CAN YOU SEE IT AGAIN!

Answer (score 0):

You `delete l4`, but you never change `l3`, and it points to `l4`s memory (now deleted) which still contains the data ('c')

You need to

```
l3->setNext(NULL);
```

to remove the element from the list (and you must still delete it of course)

To use the `deleteElement` function, you would need to change it to iterate through the list (Pseudo code):

```
void deleteElement( Element head , Element toBeDeleted)
{
    //are we deleting head (the first element of the list?) 
    //yes then head should be nulled, and delete as normal

    current = head ; ancestor = head;

    //scan through list (current becomes current->next until no more)
    //until we find toBeDeleted
    //maintain ancestor as we go 

    //if found set ancestor->next to current->next
    //delete toBeDeleted
}
```